# Round Decimal Points in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have some columns in Amazon Athena the show line item costs.

The numbers show up in the select statement like this:

```
0.0137222782
0.005445911
8.237777E-4
```

I'm just doing a basic select on the info:

```
SELECT line_item_unblended_cost FROM company_cost_allocation WHERE line_item_unblended_cost !=0;
```

How can I round these totals to the second decimal point?

Comment: Have you tried the `round()` function?

Answer (score 10):

Simply, try `round` function, it will work.

```
#select round(0.0137222782,2);
#0.01
```

similarly,

```
#select round(0.0137222782);
#0.0
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/math.html).